# mysqldump: unknown option '--:q'

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

mysqldump worked fine just yesterday.
Today I tried to dump a database and got this error message

> mysqldump: unknown option '--:q'

Nothing helps, I checked all the parameters, runned "mysqldump -h", "mysqldump" without options - always the same result.

I suppose the executable is corrupted in some way or .. I really don't know. 
I think maybe I should try to reinstall the mysqldump but I`m not sure how to do it without breaking the currently working mysql server to stop.

Console mysql client is working fine. 
MySql version is 5.1.54-1. The server is Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Please tell us what you were running.  We can't shed any light on the failure of a command we can't see.

Comment: mysqldump without any options gives me this error too.

Comment: What, just `mysqldump` with no options or flags?

Comment: yes, this was the case. I found my problem, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be someone was editing the file with `vi`, tried to quit (:q) while in writing mode, didn't notice and then saved the file. If this is the case edit the file and remove the extra ":q" characters.

Edit: Is there an alias for `mysqldump` or another script with the same name in the current path (`which mysqldump`)?

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. While editing the config file my.cnf "someone" typed accidently ":q". After I removed it, everything is ok. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error means that somewhere in your command you've written a switch like `--:q`.

Also, instead of `--q`, consider `-q`, or it's full switch `--quick`. Or perhaps you were trying to do the `quote` command? In which case `-Q` or `--quote` would suffice.

Comment: the problem is that i am typing just > mysqldump and I hit enter. The same error message appears

Comment: Edit your original post with the command you're trying to do. We'll help you debug it.